# Fix widget in bottom space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need some help with a layout.

I need put some widgets inside a "Scrollview" but keep the buttoms in the bottom space of screen.

[Image with a "Scrollview" with some textFields inside, and under de "Scrollview" a Rows containing two buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueKFi.png)

So if I change orientation the Layout will keep buttons at bottom and will scroll the widgets above.

How can I made it in flutter, I tried to use the Stack, Listview and others approaches, but i didn't have luck

Comment: It will much easier for others to help you if you provide some code of what you have tries so far and a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Multiple ways. I recommend you either using a [Scaffold](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) or a [Column](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html):

If you are already using a Scaffold in your app, just add `bottomNavigatorBar` as a Parameter, your bar you want to have at the bottom in it and make sure the rest of your layout is located under it's `body` tag.

Otherwise you could use a Column:

```
Column( 
children: <Widget> [ 
Expanded(child:ScrollView(..),),
 yourBottomBar, 
] )
```

Or Flutter also has a [Positioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) widget which you can use in combination with a Stack:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    // some stuff
    Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      child: yourBottomBar
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: I'm using listview, scroolview not exists in flutter or exist?

I did, but the problem now is the "Scrollview" is overlapping the buttons, the "Scrollview" is not align with the top of button in bottom space

Comment: Worked!! I needed move out the buttons to out from lisview, e I used the Expand how you said, thanks

Comment: it's gives me A RenderFlex overflowed if the child become bigger

Comment: This is more of a hack than anything else.

Comment: @OjonugwaJudeOchalifu seems OK to me. Have any better idea?

Comment: I'll get back to you on that in 10 working days